# Conditional appearance of a comment box - based on answer to question in a survey

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a ten question survey. Each question has the same radio button choice for answers:

- Strongly Disagree
- Disagree
- Neutral
- Agree
- Strongly Agree
- N/A

We only want a comment box to appear if someone answers in the neutral/negative:

- Strongly Disagree
- Disagree
- Neutral

How can I accomplish the above?

FYI - our audience base is insurance agents - so we have had problems in the past with the use of JS - as they don't have it enabled - and they would just abandon the form is asked to download it.

Comment: FYI - I'm doing this in SFMC - not SFDC proper.  Also SmartCapture form is out as it cannot span multiple pages and write to the same row on a DE.  SF says it can - but doesn't seem to have the resources to help us.

Comment: JS is basically a requirement if you want dynamic webpages, not sure why they don't have it enabled in today's world. Only way I can see to avoid it is to rerender whole page on submit then display using SSJS or AMPscript rendering on the server side

Comment: Thanks Doug - I appreciate the input! - Marie